# Relationship between Microsoft Teams app and Azure (AAP) app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to create a Microsoft Teams messenger bot. To do this:

- (1) I've created a separate Azure (AAP) app through portal.azure.com to create a flow to get an access token from the Teams admin, to access information about the tenant we install the app in, to proactively install my app.
- (2) I've also created a separate Microsoft Teams app through the Teams Developer Portal (dev.teams.microsoft.com) and included the ID from the Azure app in its settings:
  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1wal.png)

However when I try to proactively install the Teams bot from (2) using the Graph API with access token from (1), I get this error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "AAD App Id '5f18a460-4e3b-4833-acac-9a6281e964d7' is not allowed to manage the Teams App '8782dd91-2afe-45e9-8906-858553f7675c'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-09-12T21:19:56",
            "request-id": "b50af1b2-b697-403f-b0be-4f66486f4ac1",
            "client-request-id": "b50af1b2-b697-403f-b0be-4f66486f4ac1"
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I need to create the Teams app *through* the Azure portal instead of through the Teams developer portal for my Azure app to have access to install the Teams app for a user? If so how can I do that?

thanks!

Comment: Have you provided and consented the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages#permissions) mention in the doc?

Answer (score 0):

•   The procedure that you have followed to create a team’s messenger bot is not recommended and way round about rather than creating the bot using the Microsoft Team developer portal and then deploying it to the Azure portal for availability to all.

•   Since, the procedure that you are following requires a token to be retrieved from the Azure AD for authentication to the team’s bot app and then pass it to the teams app for logging in with the AAD credentials, the token flow happens over the public internet where a tunnel is not provided between Teams and the bot app due to which the token information might not be redirected to the teams app.

•   Also, when you are using the second method where in you are using the Microsoft teams developer portal for developing a bot app in teams and referring the ID of the application creating in azure in the code, there might be a conflict where in an Azure AD application regarding the bot app created by you is already created in M365 tenant for provisioning and deploying purpose at the time when you are signing up for Microsoft teams developer portal due to which the app created and hosted by you may not be able to establish a connection to the azure app created or the one already created/linked in azure.

•   When you create an app in Microsoft Teams, the app manifest is submitted to the developer center for teams for publishing and code integrity violation check purposes after which a communication tunnel based on public urls is created between the Teams and the bot app code which in your case doesn’t seem to happen. Thus, the issue.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/first-app-bot?tabs=vscode

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/admin-settings